# Set-UID Capability Leak Attack

Tags: file-descriptors, setuid

I have a `C` program to demonstrate the `capability leak` attack regarding set-uid.

```
// cap_leak.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main()
{  
    int fd;  char *v[2];  
    /* Assume that /etc/zzz is an important system file, and it is owned by root with permission 0644. Before running this program, you should create the file /etc/zzz first. */  

    fd = open("/etc/zzz", O_RDWR | O_APPEND);

    // Print out the file descriptor value  
    printf("fd is %d\n", fd);    
    if (fd == -1) 
    {     
        printf("Cannot open /etc/zzz\n");     
        exit(0);  
    }  
    // Permanently disable the privilege by making the  
    // effective uid the same as the real uid  
    setuid(getuid()); 
    printf("Real user id is %d\n", getuid());    
    printf("Effective user id is %d\n", geteuid());    

    // Execute /bin/sh  
    v[0] = "/bin/sh"; v[1] = 0;  
    execve(v[0], v, 0);        
}
```

Originally, `cat /etc/zzz` gives:

```
this is a very important file
```

Now I compile this program:

```
gcc -o cap_leak cap_leak.c
```

Change the owner to root and turn the setuid bit on:

```
sudo chown root cap_root
sudo chmod 4755 cap_root
```

Now when I run the program from a normal user, I get a shell prompt:

```
fd is 3
Real user id is 1000
Effective user id is 1000
$whoami
$seed
$echo bbbbbb >&3
$cat /etc/zzz
$this is a very important file
 bbbbbb
```

The last write to `fd = 3` i.e, `/etc/zzz` is successful, although after opening the file the `setuid()` function is called which basically sets the real, effective and saved uid to the original uid. My question is, why the last write is successful even though it is performed after `setuid()` and to prevent capability leak in this case, where should the `setuid()` be placed and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other place you should put the `setuid()`, you should not leave the file open for write.

The reason for that is that the permissions are checked when the file is opened, not at every `write()` call.

There is no reason to leave the file open with write access if the unprivileged shell is not supposed to write to that file.